# Click event doesn't produce any result

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

total noob here.

I'm writing a countdown timer that starts clicking on a "Start" button. No matter what I do, the timer always starts at the load of the page. And I mean that, when using live server on VS Code, every time I give the page a save, the timer starts.
No error appears in the console.
Probably I'm missing something really basilar, but I would love some help!

```
const btnStart = document.querySelector('.start');

const startTimer = function() {
let time = 10;

const timer = setInterval(function() {
    const min = String(Math.trunc(time/60));
    const sec = String(time%60);
   
    time --;
    input.value = `${min.length <= 9 ? min.padStart(2, 0) : min}:${sec.length <= 9 ?sec.padStart (2, 0) : sec}`;
    if(time == 0){
        setTimeout(function(){clearInterval(timer);
            startTimer();}, 1000)
        
    } 
}, 1000)
}

btnStart.addEventListener('click', startTimer);
```

Html elements part:

```
<div class="main-container">
        <input type="text" class="input" placeholder="MM:SS">
        <div class="buttons-container">
            <a href="" class="button start">Start</a>
            <button class="start">START</button>
            <a href="" class="button stop">Stop</a>
            <a href="" class="button reset">Reset</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: [Seems to work fine](https://jsfiddle.net/ck7eaLo9/)?

Comment: For me too! Can't explain why it isn't working.

Comment: how are you implementing it in your html?

Comment: This click event is just js, and the whole js script is linked at the end of the HTML body.

Comment: Open the dev console (`Ctrl`+`Shift`+`i` on most computers, `Command`+`Option`+`i` on Mac) and edit the question with the error if it exists

Comment: Unfortunately no. Console is totally clear.

Comment: Can you give us any more information? Do you have a `<button>` element with a class "start" (and it's the only element with the "start" class)? Do you have an `<input>` AND the variable `input` assigned to that DOM Element? Are you developing on a website or locally?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Developing locally and yes, both the button and the input are right in term of class names.

Comment: What does "the timer always starts at the load of the page." mean? This question will be closed unless you add additional debugging details (NOT in comments, edit the question to make it appropriate for Stackoverflow). If we can't reproduce the error we can't assist in answering.

Comment: Do you accidentally have a `btnStart.click()` or something similar somewhere else in the code? Also maybe try a `Ctrl`+`f` or `Command`+`f` and search of `startTimer` and `timer` to see if you're accidentally calling it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You new edit to the question answered the question.

You're using VSCode LiveShare. When you save, it doesn't actually reload the page, it just loads the changes.

Since you're recursively calling `startTimer();` (it's calling itself inside a `setTimeout`), it will never stop since it's not a full reload.

The easiest way to fix this is to reload your page manually (`Ctrl`+`r` or `Command`+`r`)

The harder way you could solve this is to store `timer` as a global variable, and on load, if `timer` exists, run `clearInterval(timer)`